# Which number base contains the most Palindromic Numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, graphing-functions, number-systems, palindrome

---

### Plotting Palindromic Numbers

I made a script that checks numbers through number bases and plots a black pixel if the number is a palindrome in the corresponding base.

If we check the first $256$ numbers (width) and first $256$ number bases (height), and draw a picture by starting in the upper left corner, we get [the image on the left](https://i.stack.imgur.com/18AYT.jpg).

If we also connect all the $2$-digit palindromes with straight lines, we get [the image on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U46Hw.png).

$\hspace{1.15cm}$[image] $\hspace{1cm}$ [image]

- The **black triangle** represents **one-digit-palindromes**.
- If we look at the **$2$-digit-palindromes**, they form straight lines.
- If we look at the **$3$-digit-palindromes**, they form parabolas. The first parabola is colored in yellow and located above the red lines as it can be seen on picture on the right.

In general, $D$-digit palindromes form a set of polynomials of degrees $D-1$. But it's not clear on which exact points on those curves the palindromes appear, except for the lines.

---

### Counting Palindromes

The thing that I'm interested in, is counting the palindromes outside the black-triangle-region, among $n$ first natural numbers.

> If we count the palindromes among first $n$ numbers in all natural
>   bases $b>1$, but **ignore the one-digit-palindromes** (ones that fill up
>   the black triangle on the picture),
>
> Which base $b$ will contain the most palindromes?

**By computation,**

Start counting at $n=1$, then the first palindrome occurs at number $3$ in base $2$.
 Base $2$ will hold most palindromes until,

Base $3$ has most most palindromes at $n=26$, 

 Then base $2$ has most palindromes at $n=27$,

 Then base $3$ has most palindromes at $n=28$,

 Then base $2$ has most palindromes at $n=31$,

 Until base $4$ takes the lead at $n=55$.

After that, all bases $b\ge5$ seem to follow an equation and overtake the lead when $n$ reaches:

$$b^3 - 2b^2 + 4b - 2$$

I checked this for bases up to $16$ and confirmed that $n$ follows the equation: (Starting at $b=5$)

$$ 93,166,271,414,601,838,1131,1486,1909,2406,2983,3646 \dots$$

With my computations so far, I would conjecture that this equation holds for all $b\ge5$

> But this requires a proof.
>
> It would be even better if someone can show how to arrive at this
>   formula without relying on computation.

**So far**, [Mastrem showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2233881) why the overtake happens at $b^3 - 2b^2 + 4b - 2$, which makes sense. But it is still not shown that it is the only, and the first, overtake that happens.

---

Deeper analysis of the plot can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2238944/palindromic-numbers-fractal-or-chaotic-number-3).

Comment: I guess if you only check numbers up to $n$ then the best you can do is just take base $n+1$, since then all numbers are single-digit and thus a palindrome.

Comment: @vrugtehagel I'm not counting the single-digit palindromes as stated in the problem, since the task is trivial then.

Comment: Without thinking too much about it I would guess that a larger base implies more palindromes. Because a number $x$ that's a palindrome in base $b$ will also be a palindrome $y$ in base $b+1$, even though the values of $x$ and $y$ are different. For example, every possible palindromic string of zeros and ones in base 2 is also a palindromic string in base 3, even though they represent different numbers. Like $101$.  $101$ in base 2 is 5 and $101$ in base 3 is 4. Different values but still a palindromic presentation. And a larger base means more digits to use means more palindromes to construct.

Comment: @tilper: But the same palindromic string in a higher base may already be above the limit $n$. For example, if $n=6$, then $101$ is a valid palindrome in base $2$, but not in base $3$, as $10>6$. Also note that due to exclusion of single-digit palindromes, as bases $\ge n$ will automatically get the count $0$.

Comment: Ah, got it.  Wasn't sure at first if you intended for $n$ to be fixed so as to find the $b$ with the most palindromes for that fixed $n$, or just the $b$ with the most palindromes at all.

Comment: @tilper: Without a limit, in all bases the number of palindromes would be infinite.

Comment: We can rewrite $b^3-2b^2+4b-2$ as $b.b^2-2b^2+3b+b-2=(b-2)b^2+3b+(b-2)$. This shows more clearly that the overtakes happen at $333_5, 434_6, 535_7$ etc.

Comment: True.  Let us all not forget the fact that I did say I wasn't thinking too much.  :P  $\qquad$

Answer (score 1):

We have:
$$b^3-2b^2+4b-2=(b-2)b^2+3b+(b-2)$$
and:
$$b^3-2b^2+4b-2=(b-1)^3+(b-1)^2+3(b-1)+1$$
For all $b\in\mathbb{N}_{\ge 5}$, let $f(b)$ be the amount of palindromes in base $b$ up to and including $b^3-2b^2+4b-2$ and let $g(b)$ be the amount of palindromes in base $b-1$ up to and including $b^3-2b^2+4b-2$. Now, from the very first 'factorization', we see that:
$$f(b)=(b-3)b+4+(b-1)=b^2-2b+3$$
Because, if a palindrome starts with a digit $1\le k\le b-3$, we can choose whatever digit we want for the middele one and when the palindrom starts with $b-2$, we have $4$ options for the middle digit. Also, we can choose a total of $b-1$ two digit palindromes.

Now for $g(b)$. We split this case up into $4$ digits and $3$ digits. If we have a $4$ digit number, the first digit is a $1$ and the second one is $1$ or $0$, so the only two options option are $1111_{b-1}$ and $1001_{b-1}$. All $3$ digit numbers are possible, a total amount of $(b-2)(b-1)$ numbers (because we can't choose $0$ as the leading digit). So when we also include the two digit palindromes:
$$g(b)=2+(b-2)(b-1)+(b-2)=b^2-2b+2=f(b)-1$$
And since $b^3-2b^2+4b-2$ is a palindrome in base $b$, but not in base $b-1$, the base $b$ 'takes' over at $b^3-2b^2+4b-2$.

The thing I'm still trying to prove is that this is the first time $b$ 'takes over'. As soon as I know, I'll edit it in